# str_replace url not working

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I'm trying to change the url of an image via `str_replace` in my Wordpress template but it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
$featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');

$featured_img_url = str_replace("http://www.mydomain.it/",
                                "https://newdomain.it/mysite/", 
                                $featured_img );

<div style="width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            background: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>') #fff top center; 
            background-size: cover; 
            border-radius: 1%; 
            min-height: 200px;"></div>
```

The `div` background keeps echoing the original url.

I've already tried using both single and double quotation marks. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: if it can be of any help, this code is running inside the Wordpress loop.

EDIT: this is what I get when I use `var_dump` on `$featured_img`:

```
string(105) "http://www.staging1.serialfreaks.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Game-Of-Thrones-7x07-The-Dragon-and-The-Wolf-11.png"
```

And here's the full loop with the correct URLs:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 

$featured_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');

$featured_img_url = str_replace('http://www.staging1.serialfreaks.it/','https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/serialfreaks/', $featured_img );

?>

<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div style="width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>') #fff top center;
                    background-size: cover;
                    border-radius: 1%;
                    min-height: 200px;">
        </div>

    ...
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: What is the value of `$featured_img`?

Comment: can you plz echo `$featured_img ` and let us know its value

Comment: it's the full image url, like `http://www.mydomain.it/uploads/file.jpg`

Comment: Then `$featured_img` is not what you think it is. Where's the `var_dump()` debugging?

Comment: Add the exact URLs including `$featured_img` and other URLs.We won't do anything with your website! Maybe the encodings are different!

Comment: There is probably something going on between your `str_replace()` and the HTML that you're showing. It might be helpful to see the full loop that you mentioned.

Comment: I've just edited my question with `var_dump` of `$featured_img` and the full loop

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$featured_img_url = substr_replace("http://www.mydomain.it/", 
                                   "http://www.mydomain.it/".$featured_img, 23 );
```

Let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is very **wrong** with your `$feature_img` value. When I ran your code it shows what is expected. You can debug it through `var_dump($featured_img)`. It could have some unnecessary characters on your url or some unwanted space. See **DEMO** when I try with your posted example `$feature_img` url : https://eval.in/1039310

```
<?php
$featured_img = 'http://www.mydomain.it/uploads/file.jpg';
echo "Before Replace=$featured_img\n";
$featured_img_url = str_replace("http://www.mydomain.it/","https://newdomain.it/mysite/", $featured_img );
echo  "After Replace=$featured_img_url\n\n";
?>
<div style="width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            background: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>') #fff top center; 
            background-size: cover; 
            border-radius: 1%; 
            min-height: 200px;"></div>
```

**Program Output**

```
Before Replace=http://www.mydomain.it/uploads/file.jpg
After Replace=https://newdomain.it/mysite/uploads/file.jpg

<div style="width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            background: url('https://newdomain.it/mysite/uploads/file.jpg') #fff top center; 
            background-size: cover; 
            border-radius: 1%; 
            min-height: 200px;"></div>
```